# While loop comparisons of strings/characters with fgets

Tags: c, char, fgets

I am trying to get user input with `fgets` in C and am having trouble using the while loop.

Here is the code I am using:

```
char input[300];

fgets(input, 300, stdin);

while(strcmp("Quit", input) != 0) {

    fgets(input, 300, stdin);

}
```

When I enter `Quit` the loop continues and does not terminate and I don't understand why this is so.

Comment: And the duplicate is itself a duplicate of [`strcmp()` on a line read with `fgets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404794).

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` stores the new line character in `input` as well. Either remove it manually, or compare like this:

```
while(strcmp("Quit\n", input) != 0)
```

Comment: How does one remove the newline character?

Comment: Is that similar to the EOL?

Comment: @code Something like `input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';`.