# strcasecmp is not returning zero

Tags: c

I want to know why strcasecmp() is returning 0 the first time I use it but not the second.

In this example i'm specifically entering "hello world" into standard input.
Instead of printing 0 0 it's printing 0 10. I have the following code.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(void) {

  char input[1000];
  char *a;

  fgets(input, 1000, stdin);

  a = strtok(input, " ");
  printf("%d\n",strcasecmp(a,"hello"));  //returns 0 

  a = strtok(NULL, " ");
  printf("%d\n",strcasecmp(a,"world"));  //returns 10


  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps `a` will have a new line character. The debugger can confirm this

Comment: @EdHeal I feel stupid now. Thankyou very much!

Comment: Bear in mind that there is no function called `strcasecmp()` in standard C.   Your tagging needs to specify that (e.g. linux).

Comment: Related to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2404794/694576 if not a duplicate to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The newline, you have entered after `hello world` is part of the `world` token because you use space as token separator.

If you use `strtok(input, " \n");` instead of `strtok(input, " ");` the program will behave correctly. In fact, you probably want to use tabulator as token separator as well.

The whole program will be:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(void) {

  char input[1000];
  char *a;

  fgets(input, 1000, stdin);

  a = strtok(input, " \n\t");
  if (a == NULL) return(-1);
  printf("%d\n",strcasecmp(a,"hello"));
  a = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
  if (a == NULL) return(-1);
  printf("%d\n",strcasecmp(a,"world")); 


  return 0;
}
```