# c: strcmp Not Stopping At Conditional Statement It Should Hit

Tags: c

I'm learning to create multi-file programs for one of my classes. Ultimately I need to implement a stack and do some stuff with the stack. Before I began implementing the stack I wanted to make sure my files were all linked together properly with a header file. For some reason when the user inputs "pop" or "print" the conditional statement is not triggered and the method in stack.c is not called. I've been looking at this for awhile and haven't gotten anywhere. Thank you for the help

**MAIN.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stack.h"
void pop(char list[]);
void print(char list[]);
void push(char list[]);   
int main(void)
 {
    char input[5];
    char test[5];
    while( strcmp("exit",input) != 0)
    {
             printf("Please enter a command. \n");
            fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
                    if(strcmp("pop",input)==0)
                    {
                            pop(test);
                    }
                     else if(strcmp("push",input)==0)
                    {
                            push(test);
                    }
                    else if (strcmp("print", input)==0)
                    {
                            print(test);
                    }
    }
     return 0;
   }
```

**STACK.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

void pop(char list [])
{
    printf("This is in the stack file in pop\n");
}
void push(char list [])
{
    printf("This is in the stack file in push\n");
}
void print(char list[])
{
    printf("This is in the stack file in print\n");
}
```

**Console Output**

```
Please enter a command.
push
This is in the stack file in push
Please enter a command.
Please enter a command.
pop
Please enter a command.
print
Please enter a command.
Please enter a command.
exit
```

Comment: Your 4+ char commands aren't consuming the newline in your input. `input` is too short.

Comment: Read the [fgets man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets): " If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer". That is, your `input` buffer will contain a newline (ignoring the fact that the buffer is not actually big enough). So you either need to strip off the newline character or your `strcmp` need to include it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404794/strcmp-on-a-line-read-with-fgets

Comment: Also *undefined behaviour*  with the first `strcmp("exit",input)` since `input[]` being a local variable is not automatically initialised.

Comment: First, make the buffer bigger, e.g. `char input[100];`. Second, [remove the newline from the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776).

Comment: Thank you guys it was an undefined behavior. I made the arrays bigger and nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

1. The line read by `fgets()` will include `\n` at the end. Test for `strcmp("word\n", input)==0`.
2. 5 is not sufficient size for `input` since you need to be testing for newlines (`"push\n\0"` is 6 bytes; `"print\n\0"` is 7 bytes)
3. You test for `strcmp("exit", input)` without `input` being initialized. This is undefined behavior. Set `input` to be all-zeroes before beginning your loop.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest use of strstr() instead of strcmp(). If you use strstr() then there is no need to mention '\n' in the string to be searched.

The strstr() function finds the first occurrence of the substring needle in the string haystack.
For better understanding you can visit,
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html

Code will look like,

```
while( strstr(input,"exit") == NULL)
{
    printf("Please enter a command. \n");
    memset(input,0,sizeof(input));
    fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
    if(strstr(input,"pop"))
    {
        printf("pop\n");
    }
    else if(strstr(input,"push"))
    {
        printf("push\n");
    }
    else if (strstr(input,"print"))
    {
        printf("print\n");
    }
}
```

I agree with  @Govind Parmar that 5 bytes are not sufficient for input buffer. You need to declare input buffer with 7 bytes.